# Let's Encrypt certificate with Docker

Tags: apache, docker, ssl

I'm new to Docker, I've been trying to set up an environment that emulates a standard LAMP stack do develop PHP applications locally and easily deploy them

So far I've followed [this setup](https://github.com/thivi/DockerLAMPStack) for my Docker, it seems to be working fine, but I'm having trouble with certificates. On a normal server I would just run Certbot, select the Apache site to enable HTTPS for, and be done with it.

On Docker however I have no idea how to do this. My certificates should be placed inside `./cert/`. Does that mean that I have to run commands to add the PPA, install Certbot, then create a certificate and place it in the folder I want? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Googling brought me to a whole lot of Docker images that automatically create a Certificate and also create an Apache instance, but I'd like to keep this as vanilla as possible.

What is the process of using a Let's Encrypt certificate with Docker?

Should I even install one locally or is that bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

> My certificates should be placed inside ./cert/. Does that mean that I have to run commands to add the PPA, install Certbot, then create a certificate and place it in the folder I want? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

Yes, you can proceed like this and store the certificate into a volume which point to ./cert/.

> What is the process of using a Let's Encrypt certificate with Docker?
>
> Should I even install one locally or is that bad practice?

There is no certificate management with docker. Yes you can manage the certificate in your container but it would be hard to maintain it ( renewal etc).

The correct approach would be to use traefik as a load balancer it has built-in certificate manager which handle all the necessary.